# Software to Administrate Network Connections

Tags: windows, networking

I need a software to admin my networks connections, I go to diferents clients with my notebook and I have to manually change my settings. Best software to do this? Windows and Mac, I use a MacBook with Vmware Fusion.

Comment: When you say manage your connections, are you asking "How do I disconnect and reconnect drives to different systems in a batch"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Network tab in your system preferences and create a new "location" for every network that doesn't work with the default "automatic" profile.
That should help for most situations. For some special networks, try to fiddle with particular settings in the corresponding location's settings.

HTH - at least for the Mac OS. Don't have a solution for Windows, though IIRC there's some for road warriors.